# How can I sort a table by a column for numeric letter first, then case sensitive for alphabet letters

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g, sql-order-by, nls-sort

How can I sort a table by a column varchar2 with characters in varying cases: upper, lower, numeric string

For example, when I do an order by the column NAME, the data of the column are:

```
ANNIE
BOB
Daniel
annie
bob
1abc
```

The expected result is:

```
1abc    
ANNIE
annie
BOB
bob
Daniel
```

Comment: Where would you place 'Ben'?

Comment: between BOB and annie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complicated. Normal sort order is aa, aA, Aa, AA, ab, aB, Ab, AB, a1, A1, 1a, 1A. So same names are grouped together and then lower case comes first. Digits come after Z.

This is close to what you are after. You want Ben to come before BOB, because you care about BEN being before BOB in the first place and only then about O being capital and e being not. However, you want digits come *before* a and upper case coming *before* lower case. That makes a great difference at last.

You cannot do this easily, because while you want words (bob, BOB) be grouped as in default ordering, you want single characters be treated differently. You can first order by lower or upper to get the grouping, but that will put numbers last, you can then use binary order to get A before a.

```
order by lower(name), nlssort(name, 'NLS_SORT = BINARY');
```

I think this is as close as you get with built-in stuff. Digits last. If you want to stick to your special order, you will have to write a function for it and use that.

```
order by my_own_sort_order(name);
```

EDIT (after acceptance :-) On second thought: you want the original sort behavior only with toggled upper/lower case consideration. You can use TRANSLATE for this:

```
order by translate(name,
   'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 
   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

Comment: yeah, what you answer is right. That why I cannot get the result I want by using built-in function.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you can use TRANSLATE. See my updated answer.

Comment: Nice try. But I think this only works for English ^^

Comment: Well, just add the foreign letters you are interested in. But yes, if one wants a special ordering, maybe for many queries even, a function might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY UPPER(MyCol)
```

Comment: This just returns random result. because it treats annie as ANNIE, sometimes annie comes first, sometimes it comes after ANNIE

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```html
Select * from TableName 
Order by ColumnName Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN
```